# Returning the number of nodes within a range in a binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, count, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to code a method that returns the number of nodes in a binary tree who have a value between a range.

Here if the full code as requested:

```
public class StaffInfo {

    final String name;
    final int monthHired;

    public StaffInfo(String name, int monthHired){
        this.name = name;
        this.monthHired = monthHired;
    }


public class StaffTree implements Iterable<StaffInfo>{
    public StaffNode root;

    public StaffTree(StaffInfo c) {
        this.root = new StaffInfo(c);
    }

    private StaffTree(StaffNode c) {
        this.root = c;
    }

class StaffNode {

        StaffInfo data;
        StaffNode senior;
        StaffNode same;
        StaffNode junior;

        public StaffNode(StaffInfo data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.senior = null;
            this.same = null;
            this.junior = null;
        }
```

Here is the code for the method I have trouble with:

```java
public int numInRange(int monthMin, int monthMax) {

            int count = 0;

            if (monthMin > monthMax) {
                return 0;
            }

            if (root.data.monthHired >= monthMin && root.data.monthHired <= monthMax) {
                count++;
            }

            if (root.senior != null) {
                root.senior.numInRange(monthMin, monthMax);
            }
            if (root.same != null) {
                root.same.numInRange(monthMin, monthMax);
            }
            if (root.junior != null) {
                root.junior.numInRange(monthMin, monthMax);
            }
            return count;
```

I am mimicking an office thus each node can have a child that's a senior, junior, or same (determined by the hiring date). monthMin and monthMax are both integers representing the number of months since January 2015.

When I run the code above, I get a StackOverFlowError.

Any help is appreciated!

If the problem is unclear, please let me know in the comments and I will edit it right away.

Comment: where is your `hiredFromMonths` methods

Comment: A typo, just fixed it.

Comment: you need to pass root in numInRange method otherwise same method call infinite times

Comment: Is there a way to do this without making root an argument since the method is called on a root?

Comment: yes. but its better pass . i answered. check

Answer (score 1):

You used root as global variable thats why every time root call his child. it will be happens infinite time. You need to pass child as root in function. then u can count.

```
public int numInRange(Root root, int monthMin, int monthMax) {

            int count = 0;

            if (monthMin > monthMax) {
                return 0;
            }

            if (root.data.monthHired >= monthMin && root.data.monthHired <= monthMax) {
                count++;
            }

            if (root.senior != null) {
                root.senior.numInRange(root.senior,monthMin, monthMax);
            }
            if (root.same != null) {
                root.same.numInRange(root.same,monthMin, monthMax);
            }
            if (root.junior != null) {
                root.junior.numInRange(root.junior,monthMin, monthMax);
            }
            return count;
}
```

Try with this.

Comment: Is there way I can modify the code without passing root as an argument. For clarification, root represents "this" since the method is called on a root.

Comment: is your method in StaffTree class?

Comment: No, it's under StaffNode

Comment: i see root in StaffTree class

Comment: CatNode is a class under CatTree